# How to translate 'using terms from ...' to Javascript in an OSA Event Handler

Tags: javascript, macos, event-handling, osascript

I want to call some JavaScript code using the osascript command. The code should stay running until it receives a chat message from Messages. Ultimately, I intend to execute this from node and receive back the chat message, sender, etc.

I am able to compile a 'stay-running' JavaScript app and run it via

```
osascript -l JavaScript JSiMessageReceiver.app
```

where JSiMessageReceiver.app is

```
function run() {
    var Messages = Application('Messages');
    Messages.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    console.log('started');
}

function quit() { // should prevent app from quitting
    return true;  // according to Apple's developer release notes
}

function messageReceived(text) {
    console.log('message received: ' + text);
}
```

Of course, the `messageReceived` handler is never called, because it is not yet associated with Messages. In AppleScript this is done via

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat
        processMessage("message received", theMessage, theBuddy, theChat)
    end message received
end using terms from
```

How does this translate into JavaScript? I did not find any documentation on this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on JavaScript:

```
function messageReceived(theMessage, eventDescription) {
    processMessage("message received", theMessage,
                    eventDescription.from, eventDescription.for);
}
```

See event description of **messageReceived** function in `AppleScript Editor` - `menu Window > Library` - `Messages Event Handler Suite`.
The worked example from [Jake Wolpert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330578/jake-wolpert) is there: [Attach event listeners in OS X JavaScript for Automation (JXA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054016/attach-event-listeners-in-os-x-javascript-for-automation-jxa?rq=1)